An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge: Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir
I have an Electron app that I'm trying to package for Flatpak with Electron Forge, but I keep running into this permissions error. I've made sure that the /tmp/electron-packager directory has the correct permissions, but this issue persists; even if switch tmp directories.
Below is the full log.
yomen@pop-os:~/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend$ DEBUG=electron-forge:* npx electron-forge make
✔ Checking your system

electron-forge:check-system checking system, create ~/.skip-forge-system-check to stop doing this +0ms
❯ Loading configuration
  electron-forge:project-resolver searching for project in: /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +0ms
  electron-forge:project-resolver package.json with forge dependency found in /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/package.json +2ms
  electron-forge:require-search searching [
  '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/node_modules/@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives'
] relative to /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +0ms
  electron-forge:require-search testing @electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives +1ms
✔ Loading configuration
❯ Resolving make targets
  electron-forge:require-search searching [
  '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/node_modules/@electron-forge/maker-squirrel'
] relative to /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +1ms
  electron-forge:require-search testing @electron-forge/maker-squirrel +0ms
  electron-forge:require-search searching [
  '@electron-forge/maker-flatpak',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/@electron-forge/maker-flatpak',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/node_modules/@electron-forge/maker-flatpak'
] relative to /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +16ms
  electron-forge:require-search testing @electron-forge/maker-flatpak +0ms
› Making for the following targets: 
✔ Resolving make targets
❯ Running package command
❯ Preparing to package application
  electron-forge:project-resolver searching for project in: /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +72ms
  electron-forge:project-resolver package.json with forge dependency found in /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/package.json +1ms
  electron-forge:require-search searching [
  '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
  '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/node_modules/@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives'
] relative to /home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend +43ms
  electron-forge:require-search testing @electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives +0ms
✔ Preparing to package application
❯ Running packaging hooks
❯ Running generateAssets hook
✔ Running generateAssets hook
❯ Running prePackage hook
✔ Running prePackage hook
✔ Running packaging hooks
❯ Packaging application
› Determining targets...
  electron-forge:packager packaging with options {
  asar: { unpack: '{**/*.node,**/*.node}' },
  overwrite: true,
  ignore: [ /^\/out\//g ],
  quiet: true,
  dir: '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend',
  arch: 'x64',
  platform: 'linux',
  afterFinalizePackageTargets: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
  afterComplete: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
  afterCopy: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
  afterExtract: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
  afterPrune: [ [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] ],
  out: '/home/yomen/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend/out',
  electronVersion: '31.3.0'
} +0ms
  electron-forge:packager targets: [ { platform: 'linux', arch: 'x64' } ] +3ms
❯ Packaging for x64 on linux
❯ Copying files
❯ Preparing native dependencies
❯ Finalizing package
✔ Copying files

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/tmp/electron-packager/tmp-iytJkX/resources/app/build-dir/var/run/chrony'


Below are also the results of ls -ld
yomen@pop-os:~/Documents/bluebird-teaching-frontend$ ls -ld /tmp/electron-packager/
drwxrwxr-x 3 yomen yomen 4096 Jul 28 16:49 /tmp/electron-packager/

Completely stumped by this. I actually have a Windows install, and I'm able to run npx electron-forge make perfectly fine. However, that'll make the windows package, and not Flatpak.

You can't package /var/run. It's a virtual directory used for temporary state.

Ah I see; that would make sense why changing permissions doesn't seem to help. Why would Electron Forge be trying to package a virtual directory?

Because you didn't tell it not to.  https://electron.github.io/packager/main/interfaces/Options.html#ignore
